# How to get a dataframe with the sum of the max values in a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have something like this dataframe:

```
base = {"month": [201901, 201901, 201902, 201902, 201902], "cat": ['0101', '0102', '0201', '0201', '0203'],  "value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(base)
df
    month   cat     value
0   201901  0101    1
1   201901  0102    2
2   201902  0201    3
3   201902  0201    4
4   201902  0203    5
```

I need to group by month and get the sum of the maximum values for each category (cat).
I don't need the cat info in this resultant dataframe.

It would be something like this:

```
    month   value
    201901  3 # (1+2, from cat 0101 + cat 0102)
    201902  9 # (4+5, from the maximum value of cat 0201 + cat 0203)
```

I was able to reach this with two steps, like:

```
temp = df.groupby(['month', 'cat']).max()
finaldf = temp.groupby('month').sum()
```

The question is: is there any other elegant way to reach this, using aggregation or idmax or something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only "more elegant way" I see would be to write it in one line like:

 `df.groupby(['month', 'cat']).max().groupby('month').sum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can remove duplicates and sum:

```
(df.sort_values(['value']).drop_duplicates(['month','cat'], keep='last')
   .groupby('month')['value'].sum()
)
```

Output:

```
month
201901    3
201902    9
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: It works indeed. Despite the solution is far from elegant (in my opinion), I'll accept the answer because it offers a different approach. Thanks